# Optimizing doctrine performance: select * is a bad idea?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, partial

We are trying to optimize a project that is consumig a lot of memory resources. All of our query is done using this kind of sintaxes:

```
$qb->select(array('e'))
   ->from('MyBundle:Event', 'e');
```

This is converted in a query selecting every field of the table, like this:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1,
   t0.field1 AS field12,
   t0.field2 AS field23,
   t0.field3 AS field34,
   t0.field4 AS field45,
FROM event t0
```

It's a good ideia for performance to use [Partial Object Syntax](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax) for hydrating only some predefined fields? I really don't know if it will affect performance and I will have a lot of disadvantages because other fields will be null. What do you use to do in your select queries with Doctrine?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents

I suppose that hydration (Object Hydration and lazy loading, of course) is good until you don't know how many and what fields to pull from DB tables and put into objects. If you know that you have to retrieve all fields, is better to get them once and work with them, instead of do every time a query that is time-consuming.

However, as a good practice, when I have retrieved and used my objects I unset them explicitly (not if they are last instructions of my function that will return and implicitly unset them)

#### Update

```
$my_obj_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundleName:my_obj');
$my_obj = $my_obj_repo->fooHydrateFunction(12); //here I don't pull out from db all data
//do stuff with this object, like extracting data or manipulating data
if($my_obj->getBarField() == null) //this is the only field I've load with fooHydrateFunction, so no lazy loading
{
  $my_obj->setBarField($request->query->get('bar');
  $entity_manager->persist($my_obj);
  $entity_manager->flush();
}
//here my object isn't necessary anymore
unset($my_obj); //this is a PHP instruction
//continue with my business logic
```

Comment: Thanks @DonCallisto. Can you give me an example on how you unset your objects explicitly?